# How to add items in already declared array of object in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

**I want to add new items from array to an object**

here is my object

```
var newCourse = {
title,
categoryId,
price,
userId,
images: [{   }] };
```

**i am getting data from req.files**

```
[
  {
    fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: '312323.jpg',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
    destination: './public/uploads',
    filename: 'file-1596169590513.jpg',
    path: 'public\\uploads\\file-1596169590513.jpg',
    size: 536245
  },
  {
    fieldname: 'file',
    originalname: 'Capture.PNG',
    encoding: '7bit',
    mimetype: 'image/png',
    destination: './public/uploads',
    filename: 'file-1596169590520.PNG',
    path: 'public\\uploads\\file-1596169590520.PNG',
    size: 13572
  }
]
```

i want to add req.files.filename (which are two) to that object so it can look like this:

```
title: abc,
images:[{url: 'file-1596169590513.jpg'}, {url: 'file-1596169590520.PNG'}]
```

Comment: It's unclear what you are trying to do. Are you trying to extend the current objects with two new fields, [title] and [images] or are you trying to convert the filename property into an object with the proposed attributes [title] and [images]

Comment: @DanielTate I think he/she is trying to take the file name and and push it as a url to images array. Like this `List = [{item1, item2},{item3,item4}]` and I need `item1` and `item3` to a new array `finalList` , like `finalList=[{uri: item1},{uri: item3}]` It can easily be done using push. I think now it's clear to you. If not please let me know.

Comment: @TripleM Thanks yes you are correct, you should edit the question to reflect this more clearly. Give your example it is a good one.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var newCourse = {
  title: '',
  categoryId : '',
  price : 0,
  userId : '',
  images: [] 
};

var req = {
  files: [
    {
      fieldname: 'file',
      originalname: '312323.jpg',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
      destination: './public/uploads',
      filename: 'file-1596169590513.jpg',
      path: 'public\\uploads\\file-1596169590513.jpg',
      size: 536245
    },
    {
      fieldname: 'file',
      originalname: 'Capture.PNG',
      encoding: '7bit',
      mimetype: 'image/png',
      destination: './public/uploads',
      filename: 'file-1596169590520.PNG',
      path: 'public\\uploads\\file-1596169590520.PNG',
      size: 13572
    }
  ]
};

newCourse.images.push(...req.files.map((file) => {
  return {url: file.filename};
}));

console.log(newCourse);
```

Comment: This isn't correct because you made an array inside an array. Use the spread (``...``) operator like so: ``newCourse.images.push(...req.file.map());``.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to map on `req.files` to get the file name array as below :

```js
const req = {files: []};
const reqImages = req.files.map((file) => { url: file.filename });
```

Now, assign this `reqImages` to `images` of your `newCourse` variable :

```js
newCourse.images = reqImages;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```js
let obj = {};
let images = [];

for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    obj.url = arr[i].filename;
    images.push(obj);
}
console.log(images);
```

Answer (score 0):

use something like this:

```
for (let item of req.files) 
      newCourse.images.push({ url: item.filename });
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged on Stack Overflow because they don't explain how it solves the problem. Please edit your answer to explain what the code does and how it answers the question, so that it is useful for other users also as well as the OP.